# How do I persist the value of a Multiple-Selection List Box in a web form

Tags: infopath, custom-form

I'm building a web enabled form in InfoPath that will be deployed as the form for a form library.  The form has a group of check boxes that have been created as a Multiple-Selection List Box.  When I publish the form to the server I specify that I would like the multi-select control added as one of the columns.  After publishing I verify that the column is there.  However,  after submitting the form I see all of the values (from the form) except the value associated with the multi-select control persisted to the library in their respective columns.  It is simply blank.  Is there something additional I have to setup so that the values of the checkboxes will be persisted?  I'm guessing so since it would need to know how to compose together the selected values (ex. "choice 1;choice 4;")

Answer (score 1):

> "The form has a group of check boxes that have been created as a
>   Multiple-Selection List Box"

It is impossible to have a chackboxes or any other controls in Multiple-Selection List Box (MSLB). The choices added into MSLB appear with checkboxes in a form.

I inserted in Infopath 2010 form the multiple selection list box and entered choices in its

[image: Multiple Selection List Box Properties in Infopath 2010]

Fig.1. Multiple Selection List Box Properties

[image: Multiple Selection List Box control on design surface of Infopath Designer 2010]

Fig.2 Multiple Selection List Box control on design surface of Infopath Designer 2010

> "When I publish the form to the server I specify that I would like the
>   multi-select control added as one of the columns"

When you published the infopath form, you published the form as a whole
Probably you refer to step 5 of publishing wizard telling:

- The fields listed below will be available as columns in Sharepoint Site and Outlook fields
- The foelds listed nelow will be available as Sharepoint Web Part Connection Parameters

[image: Step 5 of Infopath Designer 2010 Publishing an Infopath from to Sharepoint From Library wizard (Columns + parameters for web parts)]

Fig.3. Step 5 of Infopath Designer 2010 Publishing an Infopath from to Sharepoint From Library wizard (Columns + parameters for web parts)

which I advise you to read and understand directly. It doesn't tell you this about library list itself.
Published it to MultipleSelLib library on my sharepoint site

> However, after submitting the form I see all of the values (from the
>   form) except the value...

Let me remind what I see (in Mozilla Firefox), when I fill a 3d form or item of a form library and save it:

[image: Filling the Multiple-Selection-List-Bo with texbox of Infopath form]

Fig.4 Filling the Multiple-Selection-List-Bo with texbox of Infopath form

[image: Saving the filled Infopath form]

Fig,5. Saving the filled Infopath form

and how it appears in form library list:

[image: Sharepoint Form Library list (with Infopath forms)]

Fig.6 Sharepoint Form Library list (with Infopath forms)

And on clicking the 3d item entry link, I see the Fig.4 where I can edit the Infopath form and save it modified

Once again:

- you are publishing the Infopath form template to a Sharepoint Form Library
- which is used for saving filled forms (items in library) to Sharepoint Form Library
- Multiple Selection List Box control in Infoapth Designer 2010 is available for **Sharepoint Form Library** type of templates but NOT available in "**Sharepoint List Form**" Infopath forms

Comment: +1 for nice answer!!